# Problem showing/hiding widgets with Flutter

Tags: flutter

It works like this (or it should work like this):
I use the Visibility() widget that always starts with FALSE (_isMsgVisible = FALSE). In initState(), I read the file and if there are no records I show the help (_isMsgVisible = TRUE). If there are records, I show the ListView with the data.
The problem is that when there is data, help appears quickly and only disappears after executing initState().
How do I control the display only after executing initState()?
Sorry for my bad English

```
class _PlaylistState extends State<PlaylistScreen>
  bool _isMsgVisible = false;
```

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _selectedPage = 1;
    _playlistDetails.clear();
    _getDetails();
  }
```

```
  Future<Null> _getDetails() async {
    _playlistDetails.clear();

    final String url = '$URL_PLAYLISTS/read.php?user=${widget.userId}';

    final mapResponse = await http.get(url);
    final responseJson = json.decode(mapResponse.body);

    if (responseJson["result"] == "ok") {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          for (Map playlist in responseJson["data"]) {
            _playlistDetails.add(Playlist.fromJson(playlist));
          }
        });
      }
    }
    setState(() {
      _playlistDetails.length == 0 ? _isMsgVisible = true : _isMsgVisible = false;
    });
  }
```

```
  _myPlaylists() {
    Expanded e = new Expanded(
      child: _playlistDetails.length == 0
              ? new Visibility(
                  visible: _isMsgVisible,
                  child: MyInfoMessageBox(
                    text:
                        "Lista somente as playlists criadas por você, podendo ser públicas ou privadas.", 
                    title: "Minhas Playlists",
                  ),
                )
              : new ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: _playlistDetails.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return _buildDismiss(_playlistDetails, index);
                  },
                ),
    );
    setState(() {
      if (_playlistDetails.length == 0) {
        _isMsgVisible = true;
      } else {
        _isMsgVisible = false;
      }
    });
    return e;
  }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you please share the code of `initState()`?

Comment: I added in the post.

Comment: You can use any state management technique such as BLOC or provider and show a circular loader until the data is loaded. Please check [this](https://blog.usejournal.com/easiest-way-to-understand-bloc-with-flutter-8ff51a989e17) example

Comment: I got it and I will try to implement. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's the default value for `_isMsgVisible`?

Comment: The default value for isMsgVisible is FALSE